# Turtle Program Running in Trinket.io but not VS Code

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a program (below) that will run in Trinket.io and will give an output to the turtle graphics window, however, when ran in VS Code it will not give an output. It doesn't give any output to the terminal even if I insert input statements. I've tried replacing the last two lines with trtl.mainloop() but that also didn't fix the issue.

```
#   a116_buggy_image.py
import turtle as trtl
# instead of a descriptive name of the turtle such as painter,
# a less useful variable name x is used
x = trtl.Turtle()
x.pensize(40)
x.circle(20)
w = 6
y = 70
z = 380 / w
x.pensize(5)
n = 0
while (n < w):
  x.goto(0,0)
  x.setheading(z*n)
  x.forward(y)
  n = n + 1
x.hideturtle()
wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I can successfully run this program if I run it on the terminal in VSCode.[image]

Did you try installing the recommended Python extensions for VSCode yet?

Comment: Where would I find a good list of recommended Python extensions? Also, this is even weirder because the turtle graphics was working  4 days ago and it just stopped working today even though I haven't touched my computer.

Comment: Try uninstalling VSCode  from your OS and follow this tutorial to start fresh: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial There's really one extension that you should install, as the tutorial showcases.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by updating my version of python to the most recent version (specifically 3.11)

Comment: It might help future readers if you can specify which version you are now using. Thanks.

Comment: Is there are a non implemented or a *bug* feature between changes produced by each updated version it should be good to share specifically where is the compatible functionability or something like that.